# Use a file as a local storage for a NodeJS or express server?

Tags: node.js

I'm working with NodeJS. I would use a local store on the server for specifics values in order to limit the API call to my databases.

So I have make some researches, and at the end of the day I wonder if a file could play the role of a data store. The file would contain just IP of users. And it's all. I just wonder if there is some security flaws or performance disclaims with this method ?

I would so use the filesystem built'in API of NodeJS to interact with the local storage file.

Any hint would be great,
Thanks.

Comment: if it is only for optimize (fewer calls to the db) why not keep a simple json-structure in memory (Read it ones from the db at startup).

Comment: Security and performance implications vary greatly depending on setup and requirements. In general, there is nothing inherently wrong with it. However. it's a very broad topic for one question. Try and narrow the question down by adding more details. Also, look into existing solutions, like [sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite) and [lowdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite)

Comment: You probably want to look into something like redis which is a key-value in-memory store. Reading and writing to the disk uncached can be a major performance bottleneck when you for example must access said file on every request .

Comment: thanks, in my case my lone requirement would be that the file is persistence, meaning between two section the file isn't reset, that's all, I'm  using NoSQL dabase on my main database, yes it's for optimization performance  purely

Comment: Okay It would be interesting to make a JSON structure in-memory. It would mean, on my production server just need to update the JSON structure with CRUD functions °login logout for example°, and if everything it's right it could persist on the server directly by this way °outside any webhost bug or shut off and other thing like that°, if I understand well.

Comment: @PatrickHollweck since I want to scale my application - several hundreds to thousands of IP - Redis sound good, thanks.